# Changing the text color on a nav bar using Materialize CSS (rails)

Tags: html, css, materialize

I want to create a navbar with a white background and black text, but have been unable to get the text in the links within the navbar to be anything but white.

Things I've tried:
- adding the class "black-text" to the li tags, to the ul tag, to the surrounding div and nav tags
- defining a class in my application.scss file for each li tag.
- adding li, nav, a { color: black; } to my application.scss file

Here is the html for the navbar:

```html
  <header class="nav">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper white">
        <a href="/" class="brand-logo black-text">GlobalPursuit</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><%= link_to "Pursuits", pursuits_path %></li>
          <li><%= join_dashboard_path %></li>
          <li><%= login_logout_path %></li>
          <li><%= trips_cart_display %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: You'll need to show us your CSS if we're to help debug it. The HTML example would also benefit from real links - SO doesn't handle ERBs or Rails helpers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this with rails, I worked for me, So if you modify the style. see in full page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  
<style>    
nav ul li a{
  color: black;
}    
</style>
</head>

<body>
<header class="top-nav">

<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper white black-text">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

</header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, run the code snippet, you'll see that the text is still white.

Answer (score 9):

As adding a style change to the html will work I would recommend staying within the materializecss framework that you have chosen.

```
<div class="nav-wrapper"></div>
```

The default to this nav bar background color is pink, but just add one of the built in colors/shades and you will get very cool effects.

```
<div class="nav-wrapper blue lighten-1></div>
```

Now my nav bar has a light blue background color.
Same applies to the text.

```
<div class="card-panel">
      <span class="blue-text text-darken-2">This is a card panel with dark blue text</span>
</div>
```

This will produce a card panel with blue text. Hope this helps.

Answer based on http://materializecss.com/color.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this on the brand to have a black text:

```
<a href="#" class="brand-logo black-text">Logo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the materialize library defines the color as white at the `nav ul a` level:

```
nav ul a {
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

To overwrite this you would have to add the materialize text-color class to the actual `<a>` tag in the nav `<ul>`:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper white">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a class="black-text" href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a class="black-text" href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a class="black-text" href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a class="black-text" href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```